# Layering google maps ios api and game/graphics framework?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, google-maps, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing an iOS app that includes a google maps api map view and a layer that contains controls to manipulate the map. Thus far I have attempted to use Cocos-2d, however there seems to be a conflict in sharing the view between cocos2d and google maps (probably because of OpenGL issues). Is there a way to share both a cocos2d view and a google maps view at the same time? Otherwise what are my other options? Thanks in advance!

Comment: seems to be what conflict? explain!